# creating bean with name webSec

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, javabeans, password-encryption

so i'm working on authentication with spring and using jwt but i got this error while i created the class of // i made some researches but nothing really worked for me

this is the class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSec extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntry jwtAuthenticationEntry;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;


    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtService;
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity.cors();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().antMatchers("/authen").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpHeaders.ALLOW).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntry)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception{
        /*this*/authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(jwtService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

}
```

and this is the error it says i have error in the line which i Double-slashed it

Stacktrace:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSec': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at com.example.banque.configuration.WebSec$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$85ab225a.passwordEncoder() ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.banque.configuration.WebSec.configure(WebSec.java:63) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:725) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at com.example.banque.BanqueApplication.main(BanqueApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: Can you provide more details like: what is the exception and stacktrace?

Comment: @Tryingmybest stacktrace added forgot to upload it too

Comment: Please, check the dependencies of each of the three autowired dependencies: jwtAuthenticationEntry, jwtRequestFilter, and jwtService. If you have any circular references you can break them by injecting fields with setter on constructor. Also if you dont have any references you can use @Lazy annotation in jwtAuthenticationEntry or jwtRequestFilter fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the source code of JwtRequestFilter. The exception means that one of the beans that you inject into WebSec has indirect dependency on WebSec. For instance, it can be that:

- Spring starts creating WebSec and needs a JwtRequestFilter to inject it into WebSec.
- JwtRequestFilter uses AuthenticationManager and neeeds it for initialization.
- AuthenticationManager is created by AuthenticationManagerBuilder.
- To configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder, a WebSec is needed. But WebSec is being just created and cannot be used yet.

What can you do?

I'd suggest to move anything not explicitly used in WebSec to a separate class:

- `passwordEncoder()`
- `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)`

Alternatively, you can use lazy initialization for beans that cause circular references. But having circular dependencies may lead to new problems later on.

And independent on this, there is another problem: The bean WebSec provides a bean of type PasswordEncoder, but in the method `configure()` you call method `passwordEncoder()` directly. Thus on some places you will have a bean controlled by Spring, on other places you will have just a Java object. In this particular case this will not lead to problems. But in other cases it could. For instance, if you use AOP to modify behavior of some bean, it will be applied to Spring bean only, not for a plain Java object created without Spring.